# SQL Server local variable not recognized as declared

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this sql:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128) ,
        @parent_table nvarchar(100),
        @parent_field nvarchar(100),
        @id_no_parent int = 0

SELECT @TableName = 'myTable'

SELECT @parent_field = parent_field, @parent_table = parent_table
FROM anothertable
WHERE table_name = @TableName

/*
if @parent_table <> @TableName
    SELECT @id_no_parent = @parent_field FROM @parent_table
else
SELECT @id_no_parent = -1
*/

print @TableName
print @parent_table
print @parent_field
print @id_no_parent
```

If I leave the code as is, the query works fine. When I uncomment the commented code, I get an error that the @parent_table local variable must be declared.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can't construct a SQL statement like that without the use of dynamic SQL; in essence, when you select from a variable, SQL Server is expecting a table variable object, not a varchar variable holding a reference to a real table.